# typeError 'str' is not callable. invoke a class function using dictionary value

Tags: typeerror, variadic-templates, self-invoking-function

#Class and function
class cf:
def duplicate(**kwargs)
....
return df[df[field].isnull()

#There is a dictionary
r={'field':'con','function':'cf.duplicate'}

#Trying to call function looping above dictionary r
for a in r:
a['function'] a['field'] #this line is showing error as str object is not callable...and as checked a['function'] is string.

need to call a class method duplicate and give output and fetching the variable from dict

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: basically i want to call a function from mongo collection...but while invoking ..t is showing str object is not collable